# Mobile Site and Website with same content / Redirect to mobile site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mobile

I have 2 issues unsolved on my app. I built a website (desktop) and a mobile site on ASP.NET. Both sites have the same funcionality, but mobile the views are different. The desktop version has a Management Module where I, as administrator, can change different things, among these... some images that are displayed in  both versions.

My troubles are the following:

1. How can I use just ONE domain to open the sites, depending on the device used
2. Considering the above item.... how can I use just one Content Folder for both sites? (different Site.css)

I will appreciate the help with the domain folder structure to make this possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to host only one website, which is perfectly possible, i would suggest making use of the user agent in your browsers. The user agent is different per browser/device. So you can easily maintain different views per device.

Open the Global.asax file and add the following  code to the Application_Start method.

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("iPhone")
{
ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf
    ("iPhone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
});
```

Then you can easily make different views in your views folder. Just make sure you add the prefix for your views:

index.cshtml

iphone.index.cshtml

You can find more information on this website: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features

I made an example of hosting one website with different layouts based on the kind of device: http://kotatgent.azurewebsites.net/

You can test this by manually changing your user agent in chrome by downloading this extension: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg

Comment: Interesting... let me try it .. and I will let u know.... thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks... i used 51Degrees.mobi. Pretty good

Answer (score 0):

your question is fairly broad, but hopefully these resources can inspire you to head in a direction to pull of what you wish

I'd pick one site, and refactor it to be mobile ready. A good way to do this imo, is to implement CSS media queries. Take a look at this [article from smashingmagazine](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) for an introduction to the topic and a few ideas to get started. With media queries, you can define breakpoints dependent on factors such as screen widths, orientation, etc. to have your site render accordingly.

Also look into implementing the javascript library [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), which may also help you with device detection. This library can help detect if the user has certain capabilities which may influence some aspects to your mobile development, and can also offer conditional resource loading based on device detection (can be highly useful if being picky on what your mobile site will load for bandwidth conservation). i.e. my desktop needs all of these desktop javascript libraries, which my mobile site may only need this one.

If it's within your capacity to start from scratch, you may be better on a clean slate, laying out the architecture you wish to move fourth with to span multiple platforms. Carefully planned use of resources such as CSS media queries and modernizr can yield a website that has the potential to look great on just about any device, all contained within one project.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I will check the info and let u know if accomplished it! :D